# How can I sort rows according minimum values and replace them in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Let's suppose I have a DataFrame :

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'Name':['John', 'Sean', 'Philip', 'John', 'Sean', 'Philip'],
     'c_1':['a','b','c','d','f','g'],
     'c_2':[1,2,3,4,2,3],
     'c_3':[2,3,4,2,1,1]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

And output:

```
     Name c_1  c_2  c_3
0    John   a    1    2
1    Sean   b    2    3
2  Philip   c    3    4
3    John   d    4    2
4    Sean   f    2    1
5  Philip   g    3    1
```

Required output:

```
     Name c_1  c_2  c_3
0    John   a    1    2
1    Sean   f    2    1
2  Philip   g    3    1
```

I need to find a row with minimum values c_1 and c_2 for each name.
c_1 has high priority (it means that (c_1 = 1) & (c_2 = 2) is more important (and required) than (c_1 = 2) & (c_2 = 1)).
I tried to use loops, but it was unsuccessfully, because I have huge DF and my PC would do that for long time.

How can I do it in the most simplest way?

Thank you so much for answering!

Comment: You can use pandas.DataFrame.sort_values() to sort the Dataframe by c_1, c_2 and c_3. Then do pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates(subset=["Name"], keep="first").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df.sort_values(['Name','c_2','c_3']).groupby('Name').agg('first')

       c_1  c_2  c_3
Name                
John     a    1    2
Philip   g    3    1
Sean     f    2    1
```

If you want to preserve the order of the names, convert the column to a `categorical`:

```
df['Name'] = pd.Categorical(df.Name, categories=df.Name.unique())
df.sort_values(['Name','c_2','c_3']).groupby('Name').agg('first')

       c_1  c_2  c_3
Name                
John     a    1    2
Sean     f    2    1
Philip   g    3    1
```